# Can't mock fetch() with jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, fetch

I hit a wall trying to mock fetch() with jest.

I've tried 2 approaches:

**Approach 1: doing it manually as follows:**

```js
const pokemon = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'fake1',
    sprites: {other: {'official-artwork': {front_default: 'picture'}}},
    types: ['earth']
  }
const fakePokemons = JSON.stringify([pokemon, pokemon])


global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
  Promise.resolve({
    json: () => Promise.resolve(fakePokemons),
  })
);

fetchData([1, 4, 7]) // this is the actual funciton call
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'other' of undefined
```

Which relates to `sprites.other.etc...` property that the function is failing to extract. I don't understand why when it's clearly there.

**Approach 2: using `jest-fetch-mock`**
code:

```js
fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify(fakePokemons));
fetchData([1, 4, 7])
```

In this case I'm stuck with:

```
FetchError: invalid json response body at  reason: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

I tried with and without `JSON.stringify()` - no luck. I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.leighhalliday.com/mock-fetch-jest) and there both approaches seem to be working

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You mistake what jest is really doing. Jest is simply replacing native `fetch` with function that will return a simple resolved promise containing an an object with a json property , in turn containing a resolved promise with `fakePokemons` as a string and it wraps it with mock utilities to monitor callings.

You shall not stringify `fakePokemons` as the expected output of `fetch.json` call is the object itself and not a stringified form :

```
const pokemon = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'fake1',
    sprites: {other: {'official-artwork': {front_default: 'picture'}}},
    types: ['earth']
  }
const fakePokemons = [pokemon, pokemon] // HERE


global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
  Promise.resolve({
    json: () => Promise.resolve(fakePokemons),
  })
);
```

You may also take care of removing all mocks with `fetch.mockClear()` after each test.

[See Jest mocks documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions) for more informations.

In the second approach, `fakePokemons` is surely stringified twice actually and leads to an error.

Comment: Hey - unfortunately this doesn't work. Like I mentioned in my original post, I tried both with and without JSON.stringify() and both ways fail. Any other ideas?:)

Comment: It should works. Are u correctly handling promises in your fetchData function ? I sometimes forget to await promise result.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had success with `spyOn` and `mockResolvedValue`. Give this a shot:

```js
// somewhere global like outside of any describe or test blocks
jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch');

// ...

// for me, it made sense to include this in beforeEach
global.fetch.mockResolvedValue({
  ok: true,
  json: () => pokemon  // note no stringify, just the data
});
```

This was inspired by an article making a case to [stop mocking fetch](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/stop-mocking-fetch).